# Ошибка RSync "The source and destination cannot both be remote." на Windows 10, хотя путь назначения не является локальным

Tags: windows-10, rsync

Поскольку некоторые инженеры даже со средним и большим стажем этому удивляются, то сперва проясню этот момент - да, на Windows 10 действительно можно установить RSync. Мне известен способ через менеджер пакетов Chocolatey.

Итак, пытаюсь выполнить команду

```
rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync" -auvz "D:/IntelliJ IDEA/InHouseDevelopment/myproject.com/03-ProductionBuild/BackEndEntryPoint.js" 
non_root_admin@160.251.43.156:/var/www/myproject.com
```

Так как IP-адрес принадлежит временному серверу для тренировки, то скрывать этот адрес не вижу смысла. А ошибка возникает

```
The source and destination cannot both be remote.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1420) [Receiver=3.2.3]
```

Какую ошибку я допустил?

Comment: Наверное вместо `D:/` нужно написать `/cygdrive/d/`

Comment: @andreymal, благодарю Вас за комментарий! Подскажите пожалуйста, cygdrive - это что? Когда задал подобный вопрос Гуглу, он решил что меня интересует  cygwin, а не cygdrive.

Comment: rsync на windows работает именно через cygwin, поэтому гугл правильно решил, почитайте про cygwin